# "Permission denied" when accessing group file

Tags: permissions

It is easy to access group files on 20.04. However, I just upgraded to 22.04 and I cannot access a group file. Is this a bug or a "feature"?

Script file located in /home/student directory:

-rwxr-x--- 1 student students 176 May 4 09:00 todolist

When I switch to the "mary" account, you can see that mary is in the students group:

command:  tail -3 /etc/group
result:  students:x:1002:student,mary

The cat command gives a "Permission denied" error

command:  cat ../student/todolist
result:  cat: ../student/todolist: Permission denied

I added the path of the script to the bottom of the .bashrc file:

export PATH=$PATH:/home/student

Then, I active the .bashrc file

source .bashrc

Then, I try to run the todolist script:

command:  todolist
result:  todolist: command not found

I rebooted and tried to access the script file.  Still, no luck.

All of these commands work in 20.04.  However, it seems like 22.04 is blocking access to the second user's account files even though they are both in the same group.

Any ideas?

UPDATE:  doneal24 asked me to check the permissions for the /home/student directory. The /home/student directory had "student" listed for the group.  I changed the group ownership to "students" and now everything works! The command that I used was: chgrp students /home/student

Thanks doneal24!

Comment: Need more information. What are the permissions on `/home/student` and what is the first line of the script `todolist`?

Comment: Permissions on /home/student is:   drwxr-x--- 16 student student 4096 May 4 10:38.  And the first line in the script todolist is #!/bin/bash

Comment: Please edit your question to include the extra information. Comments can be deleted and having to search in both the question and the comments makes life harder. However, the answer is that `/home/student` is not accessible to the `students` group. You need to chgrp the directory or open the permissions to the world.

Comment: Be aware of typos, mary is in the `student`-group, but the file `todolist` belongs to the `students`-group.